# Is there a good way to determine if a file is executable in Java

Tags: java

I'm aware you can call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file);
```

and get an exception if it is not executable, however this is unsafe since running an executable can have side effects.

I guess just checking the extension is enough on Windows, but is there a way I can read the executable bit on *nix file systems?

What is the best way to find out if an file is executable in the OS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [java.io.File.canExecute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canExecute%28%29)

Comment: Cheers for that, I expected it would be called isExecutable so I started typing "is" in the auto complete.

Comment: Just beware that this returns true for directories; so call to .isDirectory before .canExecute.

Comment: This is probably not, what you are looking for, because ist may return true for "txt"

Comment: Why does a directory return true for this function?

Comment: This method returns true if the JVM is allowed to execute the file by the securitymanager. It gives no guarantee or even indication that the file is executable.

Answer (score 4):

The class `java.io.File` has method `canExecute()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Files` class.
It has this method `static boolean isExecutable(Path path)`.
If you have just a `String` of path then you can get `Path` using `Paths` class. Like this

```
Path path = Paths.get(pathToFile);
```